# Clean the string before eval in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am POSTing a str(list) to my web service written in Django Rest Framework:

```
to_post = str(['a','b','c'])
response = requests.post(
    'https://myservice.com/',
    data={
               'field1': to_post,
    }
)
```

In my view, I receive it as:

```
class CheckVisibilitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)

class CheckVisibilityView(CsrfExemptMixin, APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    authentication_classes = []

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument, redefined-builtin
        serializer = CheckVisibilitySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            field_1 = serializer.data.get('field_1')
```

But the string I receive contains ''s so `field_1` contains `"['a\','\b','c']"`. I need to do `eval(field_1)` to turn it into a list again for processing.

How do I remove the ''s to `eval` it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that the string always contains the initial and ending " you can strip the str

```
ls = serializer.data.get('field1')     # "['a\','\b','c']"
ls = ls[1:len(ls)-1]   # get the str from 1 : len -1
field = eval(ls)   # ls = ['a\','\b','c']
```

Comment: I don't follow.